# Set the label position for seaborn facet grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I want to put the 'Month' label in the bottom center of the whole facet grid but whatever I change the coordinate in `plt.text`, the label lies in the final chart but cannot setup in the center of the whole plot.

```
ax=sns.catplot(x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', col='region', data=monthly_region, kind='bar',
        col_wrap=7, height=4, aspect=0.5, sharex=False)
plt.suptitle("Monthly Regional Sales Report (RMB), 2017", fontsize=15, 
fontweight=0, color='black', style='italic', y=1.02)
ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
plt.text(0.5, 0.02, 'Month', ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using the *figure* coordinate system, rather than the last axes. You can do this using a [transform](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html):

```
plt.text(0.5, 0.02, 'Month', ha='center', va='center', transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```